# laravel file upload on a project on a hosted project

Tags: php

I have hosted my laravel application, before this file uploads and everything was working fine, but after I put it on cpanel, File uploading is nolonger working.
'disks' => [

```
    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],

    's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
        'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
        'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
    ],

],
```

this is my code, may someone help. in my .env file I inserted my app url for the website which is working file except for file upload
Regards

Comment: Can you clarify which storage are you trying to use? And if local, do you have proper read-write access to your storage path?

Comment: Since you moved your project to cpanel and it stopped working. The issue maybe related to the storage link. have you created the storage link after moving the application ?

Comment: I have not create a storage link sir. How do I create one and revoke the permissions. How do I access the project through terminal

Comment: am using local storage

Comment: created the link but still not working